# Matrix algebra OLS estimation two parameters

Tags: parameters, least-squares

The regular OLS estimator is denoted as: b =(X'X)^{-1}X'y. My question is what if your model has more than one parameter b. In the image I have worked out the problem formulation for multiple parameter estimation using OLS.

[OLS with two parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJre5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general request in Stack Overflow is to please type things in rather than attach images.
I found the image confusing in that you use the same symbol Y to denote two very different things -- a vector and a matrix. I'll use Z for the vector.

You want to find vectors a and b to best fit

```
Z = X*a + Y*b + e where e is 'noise'
```

You can reduce this to the usual formulation by

```
A = ( X Y )
```

an n x (p+q) matrix consisting of the columns of X and then those of Y

```
c = ( a' b' )'
```

that is, stack a and b vertically
for then the model is

```
Z = A*c + e
```

because

```
A*c = ( X Y ) * ( a)  = X*a + Y*b
                ( b)
```

Note though that you now have p+q parameters and n 'observations' so you'll need to have n >= p+q